# Azure Function error handling?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have written an Azure Function, which is processing messages from an Event Hub and writes the message to Azure Table.

How exactly does error handling work in Azure Functions? How can I signal a failure in processing a message to ensure that the message is not permanently removed from Event Hub in case it has not been properly written to the Azure Table?

Comment: Have you tried to throw a classical exception ?

Comment: If you get a failure on your Azure Table insertion, can you just push the work back into the hub?

Comment: But, what is the default behavior? What happens in case an exception is thrown in my code? Will the Event Hub message automatically be re-processed automatically or is it gone?

Answer (score 0):

The event hub message will be gone: good info on that on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/12d69fe5-a770-43de-848e-5578287f6024/azure-function-event-hub-trigger?forum=AzureFunctions).

> EventHubs is intended for high-volume throughput. There's significant
>   implication ramifications here - this happens by handling events in
>   batches and processing the batches in bulk. So it's not conducive to
>   retrying individual events and poison queues.
>
> Some options:
>
> 1. If you're low volume, use Azure queues instead. This has better retry and poison queue semantics
> 2. Your handler can catch the error in user code and do your own error handling policy, such as retry or send to your own poison queue.

If you look at the [Azure Functions Bindings docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings), Storage QueueTriggers and BlobTriggers will route messages to a poison queue, and Service Bus Queues / Topics / Subscriptions handle poison messages at the Service Bus level.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion- how about use combination of EventHub + Something like Azure Queue? Meaning use event hub to funnel the high traffic data and let it trigger Azure Function, then if there is something gone wrong, push the payload to an Azure Queue so you can have a fallback handling on the Azure Queue, and potentially allow better troubleshooting. Like what Matt suggested above- high volume queue- or I should say more like a data pipeline, has limitation on retention of data, and thats by design due to the nature of the queue data.